# in xml query how to seperate all column names in one row and data in another row

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xpath, xquery

```
  declare @query xml= 
    <emp>
    <eid>1</eid>
    <ename>raju</ename>
    <did>15</did>
    <age>25</age>
    <sal>20000.0000</sal>
    <job>clerk</job>
    <address>hyd</address>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <date>2014-01-01T00:00:00</date>
    </emp>

output:=
    eid     1
    ename   raju
    did     15
    age     25
    sal     20000
    job     clerk
    address hyd
    gender  male
    date    2014-01-01T00:00:00
```

in xml query read i want like this

Comment: Please edit your question and add the RDBMS (product and version) you are using. XML is very vendor specific! And please state what you have tried so far!

Answer (score 1):

In SQL-Server this will go along this example. Other RDMBS will need different syntax, but you might get an idea:

```
declare @query xml= 
      N'<emp>
          <eid>1</eid>
          <ename>raju</ename>
          <did>15</did>
          <age>25</age>
          <sal>20000.0000</sal>
          <job>clerk</job>
          <address>hyd</address>
          <gender>male</gender>
          <date>2014-01-01T00:00:00</date>
        </emp>'; 

SELECT @query.value(N'(/emp/eid/text())[1]',N'int') AS eid
      ,@query.value(N'(/emp/ename/text())[1]',N'nvarchar(max)') AS ename
```

The result

```
eid ename
1   raju
```

## UPDATE: values in rows

Use the xml's `.node()` to read all element (`/*`) and use `local-name()` to read the element's name:

```
SELECT nd.value(N'local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeName
      ,nd.value(N'text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NodeValue
FROM @query.nodes(N'/emp/*') AS A(nd)
```

The result

```
NodeName    NodeValue
eid         1
ename       raju
did         15
age         25
sal         20000.0000
job         clerk
address     hyd
gender      male
date        2014-01-01T00:00:00
```

Comment: I want column name are one side and date will be other side.

Comment: @YogeshSharma, No need for this. Native XML support was introduced with SQL-Server 2005. I think that everything I posted here would have been working ever since...

Answer (score 0):

```
Drop table #temp -- Drop Table
Go
declare @query xml= 
    '<emp>
    <eid>1</eid>
    <ename>raju</ename>
    <did>15</did>
    <age>25</age>
    <sal>20000.0000</sal>
    <job>clerk</job>
    <address>hyd</address>
    <gender>male</gender>
    <date>2014-01-01T00:00:00</date>
    </emp>'
SELECT *
INTO #temp -- Temp Table
FROM (
SELECT  
   Tbl.Col.value('eid[1]', 'varchar(7)') eid,  
   Tbl.Col.value('ename[1]', 'varchar(7)') ename,  
   Tbl.Col.value('did[1]', 'varchar(7)') did,
   Tbl.Col.value('age[1]', 'varchar(7)') age,
   Tbl.Col.value('sal[1]', 'varchar(7)') sal,
   Tbl.Col.value('job[1]', 'varchar(7)') job,
   Tbl.Col.value('address[1]', 'varchar(7)') address,
   Tbl.Col.value('gender[1]', 'varchar(7)') gender,
   Tbl.Col.value('date[1]', 'varchar(7)') date 
FROM @query.nodes('//emp') Tbl(Col) ) as data


--Select * From #temp
Go
SELECT [Column], data
FROM #temp AS t
UNPIVOT
(
Data
  FOR   [Column] IN(eid, ename, did,age,sal,job,address,gender,date)
) AS u;

--Result
[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: Please execute the above script to get the result:

Comment: Some hints: You should not use `//emp` but `/emp`. Furthermore there's no need to write this in a table and `UNPIVOT` it. If you do not know the element's names in adcance, this wouldn't even work. Look at my answer to find a much simple approach.

Comment: @Shnugo Thanks .. Awesome.